# Oracle showing only "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed". No output after running the code

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

This is what it is showing. No output even after running the code block

```
    SQL> DECLARE
    2     message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
    3  BEGIN
    4     dbms_output.put_line(message);
    5  END;
    6  /

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Set serveroutput on; and then try.

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
   message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

Comment: Still i am getting same issue is there any alternative way to show output

Comment: Will this be applied only to the current session?

Answer (score 4):

This program I guess is a basic HelloWorld in a PL/SQL Block.
There is an extra space between the variable message and it's datatype varchar. Just remove it.
And also, while assigning the values, there mustn't be a space between a colon equal to(:=) **and** the single quotes(''). [It would work :) ]. For eg. in a PL/SQL block we use single quotes('') to declare a string.

Well I am new here. I don't know how Stack Overflow exactly works for a novice like me, but yes some gentlemen or lady has already commented about using the below command:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

Which is absolutely correct as far as my knowledge. It is necessary for executing PL/SQL Programs.

P.s. Do tell me if I am wrong anywhere. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to this:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

try and run then whole script (F5) and not only the statement
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = true;
set serveroutput on;
```